# MAUI IOS: Label Property InputTransparent=true does not work

Tags: xaml, maui, .net-7.0

I'm using a layout where there is a Label above the button. Previously, in xamarin.forms, this property worked, which allowed you to click on the button. Now it does not work on MAUI. Are there workarounds?

Works great on android, but not on ios.

Test xaml:

```
<Grid>
  <Button Text="test button" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
  <Label Text="test label"
         InputTransparent="True"/>
</Grid>
```

Hack or workarounds?

```
<Grid>
  <Button Text="test button" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
  <hacks:LabelHack Text="test label"
                   HackInputTransparent="True"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, I managed to reproduce the issue and found that you have filed a bug in GitHub([On iOS Property InputTransparent=true does not work for LABEL #14124](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14124)). Please stay tuned for this issue to avoid missing out on our development team's solution.